# Updated to Unity version 2019.1.12f1 and now have 62 errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, updates, assembly-references

Updated to 2019.1.12f1 and now have 62 errors. Project had no errors prior.

What happened:
Updated to 2019.1.12f1

How we can reproduce it:
Update from 2018.2.10f1 to 2019.1.12f1.

Most errors are assembly reference related and associated to UI Elements.

License type: Pro
Bug Reported. Case #: 1172477
Unity Version 2019.1.12f1_f04f5427219e
Computer: MB Pro Intel Core i5 2.7 GHz 8 GB ; Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB ; Mac OS X

I imagine I could go in and deactivate all references that point to non-existent packages and hope it doesn't screw anything up, but I'd like to know why the packages didn't arrive in the new build and where to find them.

Tried reimporting assets. Didn't help.

Tried deleting manifest and the newly generated one didn't help.

Expected for the project which was previously fine and working to work in the new version without 62 errors.

Comment: "how to solve 62 errors"  isn't exactly gonna get a serious answer.. just saying..

Comment: .... "I'd like to know why the packages didn't arrive in the new build and where to find them." @Lyrca

Comment: tried deleting the whole library folder and .sln?

Comment: So you changed major versions and expected zero issues?  Start with the first error, and try to fix it..

Comment: "Most errors are assembly reference related and associated to UI Elements." isn't exactly informative about the errors. Please provide us with some actual errors so we can atleast try to help you debug this.

Comment: @Menyus, I appreciate the actual constructive feedback. To everyone else, thanks anyways. I don't have trouble working through errors one at a time. I was seeking an answer to why this actually happens with new builds so that I can avoid it in the future. It turns out one of my coworkers had installed a recorder in the previous version that I wasn't aware of that was causing all of the issues. Solution to fix it provided below. Still unsure as to why the recorder broke with the new build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested, Unity answered the bug report and the fix cleared all errors. Solution below.

> Hi,Thanks for reaching out to us!
>
> It looks like the issue is caused by the Unity Recorder. The scripts used by it are referencing Libraries that were either changed or deleted. Perhaps you have installed the Recorder from the Asset Store before upgrading?
>
> Deleting Unity Recorder folder from the Assets gets rid of the errors. I have then re-installed the Recorder via Package Manager and this seems to resolve the issue.
>
> Please let me know if this helps.
>
> If you have any further questions feel free to add them in your reply.
>
> Best regards,
> Gytis
> Customer QA Team